# How to access a specific element of an index in the token returned from strtok

Tags: c, strtok

```
int index = 0;
for (char *tp = strtok(strings, " "); tp != NULL; tp = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")){
}
```

Let's say `strings[]` is something like `"Today is nice,"` the first token return would be `"Today"` right? But doesn't `strtok()` return a pointer?

So if I want to loop through the word "Today" to print each letter out, how would I do that? Could I just do `tp[index]`?

Comment: Why does code call `strtok()` first with `" "` and then later with `" \t\n"`.  I'd expect the same token set.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this:

```
int main(void)
{
  char strings[] = "Today is nice";

  for (char* tp = strtok(strings, " "); tp != NULL; tp = strtok(NULL, " \t\n"))
  {
    printf("\"%s\" ", tp);
  }
}
```

Yes `strtok()` return a pointer. The first call to `strtok(somestring, ...)` returns the pointer to the first substring, and the following calls to `strtok(NULL, ...` return the next substrings.

If you want to do it the hard way (the way you suggested) you can do this:

```
  for (char* tp = strtok(strings, " "); tp != NULL; tp = strtok(NULL, " \t\n"))
  {
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; ch = tp[i]; i++)
      printf("%c", ch);

    printf(" ");
  }
```

I suggest you read again the chapter dealing with strings in your C learning material.

Answer (score 2):

> But doesn't strtok() return a pointer?

It returns a pointer which references the first character of the C string. C string is an array of characters with *null terminating character* at the end.

> So if I want to loop through the word "Today" to print each letter
> out, how would I do that? Could I just do tp[index]?

Yes, it is the correct way. It is the same as `*(tp + index)`. You can use both forms.

To print all characters (except null terminating character) in the string:

```
for(size_t index = 0; tp[index]; index++)
    printf("Character at index %zu is '%c'\n", index, tp[index]);
```